# A Banquet for Eight

Tags: riddle

First riddle, be nice?   Hopefully it isn't too easy.

---

First is new and bullied by Second
Third claims being first to all servings
The humpback is Fourth and blames his twin for everything
Fifth is full as soon as his meal begins
Sixth has a twin he denies knowing
Seventh is last to begin eating
Eight tries hiding to be forgotten

---

**Edit:** (Solve the riddle) Who are the Eight?

Comment: Where is the question here?

Comment: Well it's a riddle, I wasn't sure if I had to state a question (to solve the riddle) or not...   Not sure if that's better?

Comment: This looks easy at first, until I tried to find an answer that fits all the clues... Hmmm

Comment: Hopefully I didn't make any clue ambiguous, : /   I might have found it easy because knowing the answer makes the clues rather obvious... I'll post a Hint if it's needed later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my guess:

> The phases of the moon. 
>  First is the new moon. 
>  Second is the waxing cresent, where the sunlit part is beginning to overtake the dark part. 
>  Third is first quarter? 
>  Fourth is waxing gibbous; it looks like a humpback. 
>  Fifth is the full moon. 
>  Sixth is waning gibbous, the twin of waxing gibbous. 
>  Seventh is third quarter. ? 
>  Eighth is waning cresent, which is almost completely dark.

I don't really understand the personalities of Fourth and Sixth, and Third and Seventh don't seem to fit.

Comment: Quarter can mean lodging/shelter.  So first quarter and last quarter can sort of mean first to eat and last to eat.

Comment: Also, a quarter moon looks like a mouth (think Cheshire Cat from Alice in Wonderland).

Comment: Nice! I was worried the Second, Third and Seventh would be too ambiguous. Especially Third and Seventh for which you had to kind of drop the eating part. (Third is First (quarter), Seventh is Last (quarter)) But it seems JS1 came to the rescue :)   The two gibbous twins clues was just to make it clear they were both 'humpbacks'.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure . Looks like

> Chess pieces.

First is new and bullied by Second

Third claims being first to all servings

The humpback is Fourth and blames his twin for everything

> Bishop

Fifth is full as soon as his meal begins

Sixth has a twin he denies knowing

Seventh is last to begin eating

> King

Eight tries hiding to be forgotten

Still in process :)